# Reduce the empty space on each side of pages

Tags: feature-request, design

Presently, the two main content <DIV>s on a SO page, `#mainbar` & `#sidebar`, have fixed widths hard coded into the CSS.  This means that even if you make the browser very wide (say, streching over two monitors), the only parts of the page that get bigger are the empty white space on either edge.  Meanwhile, if the page contains a code sample with long lines, it will have the most heinous sin of design: horizontal scrollbars.

This is even worse when trying to print, as the #sidebar is (properly) hidden, but its space is not reclaimed -- the right margin is just bigger, all while the code sample is now printed with the scroll bars.

A trivial change to the CSS, making the width of the #mainbar DIV a high percentage instead of a fixed amount, will allow us to have useful print-outs.

UPDATE:  In response to the commentors who prefer narrow columns, my suggestion of completely compatible with that --- all you have to do is *make your browser window narrower*! (Windows are not required to be maximized)

Comment: who prints web pages anymore?

Comment: print-... what??

Comment: I actually prefer the fixed-width format. It makes the text so much easier to read.

Comment: Re Printing: http://www.stackprinter.com/ and http://stackapps.com/q/179/39

Comment: CSS3 Media Queries ftw. Make it readable on normal screens but take advantage of the extra space on wider screens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stackoverflow does not horizontally scale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21631/stackoverflow-does-not-horizontally-scale) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout

Comment: [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)

Comment: Shorter lines are easier to read. There's a reason newspapers and magazines have narrow column widths.

Comment: @Cody I've heard differently, of all places, on Stack Overflow, though I cannot find the reference at the moment. I've posted a question to skeptics about it though... [Are shorter lines easier to read?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/are-shorter-lines-easier-to-read)

Comment: @DFock42 & squillman:  People who write code on a laptop on a train (no internet)

Comment: For what it's worth, I would definitely *not* be pleased if I had to resize my browser window whenever I visited Stack Overflow. If you really want wider columns, it would probably be easier to just write a GreaseMonkey script that does the job.

Answer (score 21):

I prefer a fixed page width for the following reason, which is explained so well by [*The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX*](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) (section 6.4 Page Layout).

> **WAIT!** . . . before you launch into a “Let’s make that narrow page
>   a bit wider” frenzy, take a few seconds to think. As with most things
>   in LATEX, there is a good reason for the page layout to be as it is.
>
> Sure, compared to your off-the-shelf MS Word page, it looks awfully
>   narrow. But take a look at your favourite book (I mean a real printed
>   book produced by a reputable publisher) and count the number of
>   characters on a standard text line. You will find that there are no
>   more than about 66 characters on each line. Now do the same on your
>   LATEX page. You will find that there are also about 66 characters per
>   line. Experience shows that the reading gets difficult as soon as
>   there are more characters on a single line. This is because it is
>   difficult for the eyes to move from the end of one line to the start
>   of the next one. This is also why newspapers are typeset in multiple
>   columns.
>
> So if you increase the width of your body text, keep in mind that you
>   are making life difficult for the readers of your paper.

Interestingly enough, it appears that Stack Overflow uses a page width of 110 characters, but I still find it much easier to read than any site that flows its text across the entire screen. Sure, this means that you need to scroll poorly-formatted code, but I think that's a small price to pay for more readable text overall.

If you really must print Stack Overflow articles, though, I suggest that you try [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) (more information on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/179)).

Comment: A little bird told me that StackPrinter's author owns a couple of Ink refill companies.

Comment: But, I'm NOT advocating wide columns.  I'm advocating columns where the user can choose the size themselves.   Done as I suggest, you can make them narrower just as easily as you could make them wider.

Comment: Fair enough. Then consider my answer as a reason why I would probably never use such a feature, were it to be implemented. :)

Answer (score 5):

This would be a huge, huge change across all CSS (and the engine!) for 20+ designs.

It may happen at some point in the future, perhaps, but it won't be any time soon... we're kind of committed to the current fixed width for the indefinite future.

Comment: Even if you are changing to fluid layout, **please** give users an option to select fixed page layout. I prefer fixed page layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: Do it for the print view ... but only for code snippets, which otherwise would have scrollbars. The main text should not expand, for reasons already mentioned.

(By the way, I sometimes reformat code snippets to be narrow enough to not have a scrollbar.)

Answer (score 0):

[Here be a UserScript which collapses logo and menu.](https://stackapps.com/questions/2547/collapse-header-script)

Somehow my layout is getting rather jumpy with all the hacky scripts i apply to it...