# Make use of full screen width (sample code in Safari)

Tags: feature-request, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)
>   [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers)

I use Safari, and quite often the right part of code blocks is clipped, and I have to scroll to see the text. Why doesn't the middle column scale when I increase the width of my browser window? There are big white areas to the sides, and in the middle there's clipped code. :(

Comment: It's a conscious decision as far as I know. If you start scaling the middle part, every contribution will look different on different resolutions. Line breaks and image positionings will start varying from screen to screen.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [stackoverflow-does-not-horizontally-scale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21631/stackoverflow-does-not-horizontally-scale), [page-width-is-too-small-on-stack-exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149920/page-width-is-too-small-on-stack-exchange), [can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)

Comment: Also closely related (although not really with terribly useful answers): [Wide page layout option for 1080p and 1080i screens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23580)

Comment: Why did this question get marked down. Six times!  If there is a valid reason people should provide it so others learn.  I can't see any reason though.

Answer (score 2):

The max width of Stack Exchange sites ensures the middle column's text remains nice and readable. There's lots of good answers on User Experience like [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/3623/7627) which explain why longer lines aren't always readable. I'm on a 1080 pixel wide monitor as well, and I'm darn sure I'd rather not read SE with 200+ character width lines...